# Django Template filter the query set already rendered

Tags: python, django, templates, filter, django-queryset

I have model

```
class TransHeader(models.Model):
    th_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    th_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    th_status=models.CharField(max_length=1,default=0)
```

my view:

```
class SalTransactions(TemplateView):
    template_name = "wstore/sales_transactions.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        if  kwargs['post']=='UNPOSTED':
            context['transactions'] =          
               TransHeader.objects.filter(th_type=kwargs['transtype'])
               .filter(th_status='0')
        else:
      
            context['transactions'] = 
            TransHeader.objects.filter(th_type=kwargs['transtype'])
        return context
```

my url line:

```
 path('saltransactions/<str:transtype>/<str:post>',views.SalTransactions.as_view(), name='saltransactions'),
```

my link through menu is working fine showing all records with given trans type:

```
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'saltransactions' transtype='INV' post='ALL' %}">Sales</a>

<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'saltransactions' transtype='ADJ' post='ALL' %}">Stock Adjustment</a>
```

But when I filter to show rocords having th_status='0' only I am using the following link in template:

```
 <a href="{% url 'saltransactions'  transtype=?????"  post='UNPOSTED' %}" >Unposted</a>
```

my problem is how to pass INV or ADJ to transtype from the queryset. If I assign transtype='INV' it is filtering  INV queryset in both types.

So that I can use one view, one template for all type of transactions (INV/ADJ)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in your `get_context_data` you are checking for a POST request. The link, however, is not a POST request, it's a simple GET request. You need a form that actually POSTs the data, something like this:

```
# in your template
<form method="post" action="/my/url/to/post/to">
   <input type="hidden" name="transtype" value="MY_VALUE" />
   <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

Also, in the view, it's better to check the `self.request.method`, if it is a POST or GET request. In both cases, you can access the data via `self.request.POST`, which returns the data you posted through your form. For GET requests, anything you pass into the url, so `myurl.com/?transtype=something`, will be accessible via `self.request.GET`. If you use kwargs, it might not work as expected, because there might be something else calles `post` in the `kwargs`.

You can read up on it in here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

Comment: variable 'post' is renamed as 'posted' in the kwargs so not to confuse with post method.  my problem is how to give value='INV' or 'ADJ' FOR  value="MY_VALUE".  from list  {transheader.th_type} In nutshell filtering the current template context data.

Comment: So either you can do it with a form, like I showed or you can use URL parameters, like mydomain.com/?parameter=value. You can access both, GET and POST parameters in your view easily, there should be plenty of docs on how to do that.